# Showing convergence of integrals does not imply pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can somebody verify that this counter example shows that

$\int\limits_{a}^b|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\rightarrow 0\implies f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$

is not true?

Counter example:
Let $f_n:[1,2]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be define by $f_n(x) =\frac{nx+2}{nx+1}$

and define $f:[1,2]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $f(x)\equiv1$

EDIT: Does this work on [0,2] rather than [1,2]

Comment: No, $f_n\to 1$ uniformly on $[1,2]$

Comment: Maybe try $f_{n}(x)=nx$ when $0\leq x\leq 1/n$ and $f_n(x)=1$ when $1/n<x\leq 1$ on $[0, 1]$. Use $f(x) = 1$ on $[0, 1]$ as the function it converges to. (The function can be easily modified to fit $[1,2]$. I leave that to you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your example doesn't work, note that $$ f_n(x) = \frac{nx+2}{nx+1}=1 + \frac{1}{nx+1}$$

and therefore
$ |f_n(x) - 1| = \frac{1}{nx+1} $, and
$$ \|f_n  - 1\|_{\infty} = \max_{x\in[1,2]}\frac{1}{nx+1} = \frac1{n+1} \to 0 $$
which means $f_n\to 1$ uniformly. Hence for your sequence, we have the limit $f=1$, $f_n\to f$ pointwise, and $\int_1^2 |f_n - f| \to 0$.

Your example does indeed work for the region $[0,2]$ (or $[0,1]$, for that matter.) I'll leave the proving of that to you :)

Comment: would the counter example work on [0,2], as then it would not converge pointwise?

Comment: @Loobear23 oh, it looks like yes!